# Link folder to SVN project in Windows 8

Tags: eclipse, svn, windows-8, tortoisesvn

I have a situation where I checked-out a project from SVN in Eclipse and frequently doing commits/updates from the IDE without any issue. But if I go the directory path of the project, I can't see any option to commit/update (using TortoiseSVN) and it seems that folder is not linked with any SVN repository.

Softwares used:
- VisualSVN
- Windows 8
- TortoiseSVN

Please guide how to use SVN options even from Windows explorer.

Comment: Have you tried if you are able to use the svn commands on the commandline in those paths? (e.g. `svn update`)

Comment: No, didn't try that. Will update you on this